# Naudio + Unity: How access to DeviceCount

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, naudio

I want to make an asymmetric game(VR/Gamepad). so I need some sounds out from TV and from VR headset.

I've install the Naudio plugin for unity but I can't access to the DeviceCount properties with this version.
Then, I've try with regular version. I can access to the property but Unity3D always crash after i make a change in a script.

Here is my code with regular Naudio version:

```
            using System.Collections;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using UnityEngine;
            using NAudio;
            using NAudio.Wave;

            public class Naudio : MonoBehaviour
            {
                WaveOut waveOut;
                WaveFileReader waveReader;

                // Start is called before the first frame update
                void Start()
                {
                    waveOut = new WaveOut();
                    Debug.Log("NAUDIO device " + waveOut.DeviceNumber);
                    Debug.Log("NAUDIO Count " + WaveOut.DeviceCount);

                    for (int i = -1; i < WaveOut.DeviceCount; i++)
                    {
                        var caps = WaveOut.GetCapabilities(i);
                        Debug.Log("Device Name: " + caps.ProductName);
                    }
                    waveOut = new WaveOut();
                    waveReader = new WaveFileReader("Assets/_Projet/Resources/Sounds/PowerUp.wav");
                    waveOut.DeviceNumber = -1;
                    waveOut.Init(waveReader);
                    waveOut.Play();
                }
            }
```

Can I install Naudio with no unity's crash or my only choice is Naudio-unity?

Thanks